# Decimal points with std::stringstream?

Tags: c++, string, floating-point, stringstream, iomanip

I have a bunch of integers that I put into `stringstream`s. Now I want to change the `stringstream`s into `string`s while keeping a constant precision with the `string`s. How would I do that? I know I can use `stringstreams.precision()`, but it's not working for some reason:

```
float a = 5.23;
float b = 3.134;
float c = 3.0;

std::stringstream ta;
std::stringstream tb;
std::stringstream tc;

ta << a;
tb << b;
tc << c;

ta.precision(2);
tb.precision(2);
tc.precision(2);

std::string out = "";
out += ta.str() + "\n";
out += tb.str() + "\n";
out += tc.str() + "\n";
```

Will return `5.23\n3.134\n3.0`, rather than `5.23\n3.13\n3.00`

Answer (score 60):

I think that your problem is that `precision()` sets the precision used in future stream insertion operations, not when generating the final string to present.  That is, by writing

```cpp
ta << a;
tb << b;
tc << c;

ta.precision(2);
tb.precision(2);
tc.precision(2);
```

You're setting `precision` too late, as the first three lines have already converted the floating point numbers to strings using the default precision.

To fix this, try changing the order in which you execute these statements to

```cpp
ta.precision(2);
tb.precision(2);
tc.precision(2);

ta << a;
tb << b;
tc << c;
```

This will cause the writes into the `stringstream` to use your custom precision rather than the existing defaults.

However, the effect of the `precision` modifier is only meaningful if you explicitly tell the stream that you want to use either fixed-precision or scientific notation for output.  To do this, you can use either the `fixed` or `scientific` modifiers:

```cpp
ta.precision(2);
tb.precision(2);
tc.precision(2);

ta << fixed << a;
tb << fixed << b;
tc << fixed << c;
```

This will correctly display the appropriate number of digits.

On a related note, you don't need to use three `stringstream`s to accomplish your goal.  You can just use one:

```cpp
std::stringstream t;
t.precision(2);

t << fixed << a << '\n' << b << '\n' << c << '\n';

std::string out = t.str();
```

Comment: thanks, but its not working. im still getting `3.0` rather than `3.00`

Comment: @noobcpp- Whoops!  My mistake.  I just updated this to mention that you need to use either `fixed` or `scientific` mode on the stringstreams.  Try making that change and see if it fixes things.

Comment: +1.  @noobcpp: Also, check out: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ios_base/precision/ (though they say to use 0 in a place that is giving me a compiler error).

Comment: You don't need to split out the `precision` call on a separate line: `t << setprecision(2) << fixed << a ...`

Comment: 2 years later, and this post is still saving lives! Thanks @templatetypedef

Comment: example: `#include <iostream> #include <sstream> #include <iomanip> std::stringstream ss; ss <<  std::setprecision(2) << std::fixed << my_float; std::cout << ss.str() << std::endl;`

Answer (score 8):

In C++20 you can use `std::format` which is move efficient and less verbose than `std::stringstream`:

```
float a = 5.23;
float b = 3.134;
float c = 3.0;
std::string out = std::format("{:.2f}\n{:.2f}\n{:.2f}\n", a, b, c);
```

In the meantime you can use [the {fmt} library](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt), `std::format` is based on ([godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/T67GMh)).

**Disclaimer**: I'm the author of {fmt} and C++20 `std::format`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `fixed` as well as `precision` before feeding the data to the stringstream. Here's a working example of what you intended to do:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    float a = 5.23;
    float b = 3.134;
    float c = 3.0;

    std::stringstream ss;
    ss.setf(std::ios::fixed);
    ss.precision(2);
    
    ss << a << "\n";
    ss << b << "\n";
    ss << c << "\n";
    cout<<ss.str()<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
5.23
3.13
3.00
```